# Unable to run cameracalibrator.py

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to calibrate two individual cameras as a stereocamera.
So i tried running the file cameracalibrator.py from the path /opt/ros/fuerte/stackes/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes.

Im getting an error
**File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 42, in 
from camera_calibration.approxsync import ApproximateSynchronizer**

I could not find this module camera_calibration.approxsync located anywhere.
Kindly let me know where i am missing

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52811/unable-to-run-cameracalibrator.py/) by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-13**:
I am also facing the same issue..any solution?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-14**:
perfect..thank you so much.  Later I had the issue with import cv_bridge and solved that by adding the path to cv_bridge to pythonpath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

search for appoxsync in your camera_calibration package. Then place it in the same folder as your source file. Replace the line "from camera_calibration.approxsync" with "from approxsync" and this should work. Let me know if you have any issues in this

---

Originally posted by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) with karma: 70 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1